# How to make those fancy flash banners that expand beyond their box

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, ads

I am building a flash banner, which needs at one stage to expand beyond its 728x90 box. Something similar to the Corei7 ad currently on wired.com but not as drastic. I know ads like that are annoying, but getting evicted in winter is not an option. Viewing source on pages are difficult since they are almost always wrapped up in some third party code so I am stuck.

If you can give any help I would appreciate it. I have been trying searches with different combinations on stackoverflow and google and I have not found the right combination of keywords that give me proper results.

tl;dr : Please tell me how to make a Flash banner that expands transparently beyond its 728x90 box upon user interaction.

Comment: Most of the time it depends on how your ad is being distributed and what sites it will be placed on. Are you working with a banner/ad distribution company?

Answer (score 1):

You need some JavaScript on the outside that resizes the Flash movie. This JavaScript could be triggered using [ExternalInterface](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use windowless mode so that the browser renders the application. This allows you to see behind the embedded object and see the html components behind it.

Comment: Does the flash document change its dimensions or does it originally start with the larger dimensions hidden and the javascript reveals the rest of it?

Comment: I think the flash expands: to test this, try right-clicking around the page before the animation starts (normal HTML context menu) and after (flash context menu).